# How to re-verify with password before adding data to cloud firestore in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have to update a document from the settings menu of my web app. I'm using cloud firestore as my db service. When updating the document, **I want to send those data with the verification password so that it will be re verifing the user before updating**. This cannot be done in the front end because of the security reasons. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: You should be using Firebase Authentication to authenticate your users and protect the database from illegal write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what you want to do? 
If you need to deal with updating some document by current user (in our case user should be authenticated), so you can use [Firestore Security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started). In short firestore rules help you to restrict access to your database: you can do check if user is authenticated or not, validate data before write and more. All these checks are being done on the server side, so you need not worry about your webapp. For more read [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/).

On the other hand you can use firebase cloud functions and manually send http request with Authorization header. To perform this action you need token from firebase. You can generate it by calling method on your currentUser. For more read [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Edit: If you want re-verify with password you can signIn user with password again and do next operation

Comment: When updating important fields, I want to re-verify it by password . ( Things like updating a password/ username /email) . If I write the signin again and do the next operation in client side, an attacker can just execute the second operation manually without using a password. So I want both to happen in backend. 

So according to ur answer I guess the way is to write a **cloud function** to do both in backend.

Comment: Storing password for user in firestore is not a good way. If you are storing some user data use security rules to check if user authenticated and has permissions to access only its data. Each document in user collection will have uid of the user for which document is represented `request.auth.uid == userId;` [Example here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/security/#developer_defined). Moreover in web firebase library you can update password. Follow [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#updatePassword). Firebase do extra checks to do secure.